# Show and hide elements based on index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show div based on `index` in jquery:

I have the elements like this:

```js
$('#prod_thumb li').hover(function() {

  var idx = $('#prod_thumb li').index(this);
  console.log('clicked index', idx);

  $('.product-single__photos div:nth-child(1)').hide();
  $('.product-single__photos div').eq(idx).show();

}, function() {
  var idx = $('#prod_thumb li').index(this);
  $('.product-single__photos div').eq(idx).hide();
  $('.product-single__photos div:nth-child(1)').eq(idx).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dflex" id="prod_thumb">

  <li class="">
    <div data-image-id="27745498387" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
      <img class="product-single__thumb" src="" alt="Loaded">
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="">
    <div data-image-id="27745506259" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
      <img class="product-single__thumb" src="" alt="Loaded">
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="">
    <div data-image-id="27745515027" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
      <img class="product-single__thumb" src="" alt="Loaded">
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>


<div class="product-single__photos">

  <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
    <img class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745498387">
  </div>

  <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
    <img class="product-single__photo" src="" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745506259">
  </div>

  <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
    <img class="product-single__photo" src="" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745515027">
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to show `div` that I clicked and hide the other ones. How do I do it? Right now I am able to hide one image only in the callback function.

Comment: You don't have any `<li>` to hover over...or did I miss something?

Comment: @zer00ne forgot to add. Editing the question now

Comment: In looking at your last line: `nth-child(1)` will only target *one* element - in which case would that selector have any index other than `0`? Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Santi you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select all the other elements.

```js
$('#prod_thumb li').hover(function(){
  var idx = $('#prod_thumb li').index(this);
  $('.product-single__photos div').eq(idx).show().siblings().hide();
}, function(){
  $('.product-single__photos div').show().slice(1).hide();
}).first().trigger('mouseover');
```

```css
ul {padding: 0;margin: 0;}
ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dflex" id="prod_thumb">

    <li class="">
        <div data-image-id="27745498387" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
            <img class="product-single__thumb" src="//placehold.it/30&text=first" alt="Loaded">
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="">
        <div data-image-id="27745506259" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
            <img class="product-single__thumb" src="//placehold.it/30&text=second" alt="Loaded">
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="">
        <div data-image-id="27745515027" href="" class="product-single__thumbnail">
            <img class="product-single__thumb" src="//placehold.it/30&text=third" alt="Loaded">
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="product-single__photos">

    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
        <img class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="//placehold.it/300x100&text=first" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745498387">
    </div>

    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
        <img class="product-single__photo" src="//placehold.it/300x100&text=second" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745506259">
    </div>

    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
        <img class="product-single__photo" src="//placehold.it/300x100&text=third" alt="Loaded" data-image-id="27745515027">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When I `unhover` completely, it should show the default image which is the first one but its hiding all of them

Comment: @kittu You're welcome.  Sorry I didn't respond right away.  I was working on adapting my answer.  For what it's worth, the answer now has that added if you want to compare.

Comment: Its ok. Your answer really helped me. Thank you Joseph